# Найти ближайший вторник после первого понедельника ноября

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Существуют условия:

1. Определить ближайший год к указанной дате, который делится на 4 без остатка
2. Внутри этого года найти ближайший вторник после первого понедельника ноября

Год, я вроде, верно нашел

```
-- условия - 1) В год, делящийся на 4 без остатка, 2) ближайший вторник после первого понедельника ноября
-- Найдем ближайший год к заданной дате
with 
s(d) as
(
  select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
),
h(a, b) as
(
  select level - 1, extract(YEAR FROM to_date(d, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')-365*(level-1) ) from s
  connect by level < 5
)
select h.*, mod(b,4) mod from h
```

А вот со вторником что-то никак не выйду на решение. Может будут идеи хотя бы на уровне алгоритма ))?

Comment: *ближайший год к указанной дате, который делится на 4 без остатка* Строго в плюс, или именно ближайший? *со вторником что-то никак не выйду на решение* От 7 числа ноября нужного года отними номер дня недели и прибавь 2 (нумерация зависит от NLS - требует корректировки). Ну и подсчёты веди в числах, а не в датах, дату уже на финальном этапе соберёшь.

Comment: Ближайший год получается вычитанием из года остатка от деления на 4. Или целочисленным делением на 4 и потом умножением на 4. никакие connect by не нужны

Comment: @Akina: Получается в плюс. Не подумал об этом, речь идет о годе будущего периода. Спасибо, что поправили. За алгоритм - спасибо.

Comment: @Mike: Спасибо за ответ. Но не совсем понял по поводу вычитания. Выражение не подскажете?

Comment: `trunc(extract(year from to_date(d, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))/4)*4`

Comment: @Mike: Спасибо .

Comment: Или даже `bitand(extract(year from to_date(d, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')), 65532)` т.е. сбрасываем 2 младших бита, которые как раз и есть остаток от деления на 4

Comment: @Mike Ему надо в плюс - так что надо сперва прибавить 3, а потом сбрасывать биты.

Comment: @Akina: Да, также аналогично сделал с будущим периодом: select 2011, (2011 + 4)/4, trunc((2011 + 4)/4)*4 from dual; Ведь надо прибавить 4 года и уже от них считать, как я понял.

Comment: *Ведь надо прибавить 4 года* Нет, три. Иначе из текущего високоса получится следующий високос, а не текущий. Проверьте для 2012, например... И вот ещё... а какой год нужен, если год високосный, но дата ПОСЛЕ этого самого вторника? скажем, 01 Dec 2012...

Comment: @Akina: С 2012 получаем при повышении на 4 - 2016 год. Также делится на 4 без остатка. select 2012, (2012 + 4)/4, trunc((2012 + 4)/4)*4 from dual; А вот в части маталгоритма вычисления вторника там может не сложится, видимо? Хотя, если использовать встроенные функции Oracle... Но хотелось бы решить как-то алгоритмически. Пока не понимаю.

Comment: *С 2012 получаем при повышении на 4 - 2016 год.* Это - правильно? т.е. нужен високосный, но не текущий? и независимо от дня и месяца? тогда действительно, надо прибавлять 4.  *А вот в части маталгоритма вычисления вторника там может не сложится, видимо?* Это с чего бы вдруг? PS. Вам бы эта... с учётом уже написанных уточнений и вопросов - сформулировать свой вопрос заново, и более строго, без недочётов...

Answer (score 4):

Вроде так:

```
alter session set nls_language='russian';
with data as (
    select date'2019-01-01' dt, 1 "следующий день" from dual
)
select to_char (
    next_day (
        to_date (trunc ((extract (year from dt)+4)/4)*4||'Ноябрь', 'yyyyMonth'), 
        'Понедельник') + "следующий день", 'dd Month yyyy') res
from data
;
```

> 03 Ноябрь   2020

PS Как ни старался понять смысл фразы "ближайший вторник после первого понедельника ноября", остановился на том, что это "следующий день".

Comment: Да, взял формулировку из задачи для Политеха Спб. Тоже немного удивлен такими формулировками. За ответ - спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Но вы же можете менять формулировки публикуя задачу. Составитель задачи в политехе Спб возможно хотел просто запутать студентов, а мы тут репы морщим - что такое "ближайший".